# How to append a char to NSNumber in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, nsstring, string-formatting

I have a price parameter from my API `price: 10`
I want to show it in my textfield with appending "$" after it. But it doesn't show my number anyway even with casting it. Here is my code :

```
cell.price.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",
(NSNumber*)DIC[@"items"][indexPath.row][@"price"]] stringByAppendingString:@" $"];
```

Comment: Alternatively you could attach an NSFormatter to the NSTextField that appends the $. It can even be done in InterfaceBuilder, no code needed.

Comment: @GerdK This is not only another option, but the better option. @OP: There are countries with a different currency than US dollar and in some countries the currency symbol is put behind the amount, in some countries it is placed before the amount. Use a `NSNumberFormatter`, which has a default instance for the current user settings.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad yes, it's true, thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to print an `NSNumber` you need to use **%@** instead of **%i**

```
cell.price.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ $",
(NSNumber*)DIC[@"items"][indexPath.row][@"price"]];
```

Comment: casting to `(NSNumber*)` is obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

`NSNumber` is an object, do using the format %i will not work.

```
cell.price.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ $",
(NSNumber*)DIC[@"items"][indexPath.row][@"price"]];
```

Comment: casting to `(NSNumber*)` is obsolete.

Comment: @MarekR You mean that is this case casting is needed you are correct. But casting is not obsolete.

Comment: @rckoenes Obviously he meant, that casting in this case is obsolet.